# Dota 2 lag spikes

Tags: 14.04, networking, games, steam

I've been getting some pretty bad lag spikes in Dota 2. It shows that my ping stays around 100 ms but every intense fight in the game the game would lag spike and then everyone rubberbands. This has been happening 75% of all games to me. I am on wired connection as well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you must stop all the downloads running in the back because they would be consuming bandwidth and you will experience lag. I would recommend using [Kill Ping](http://www.killping.com).

It is an online gaming application which provides a dedicated gaming route to its users to the game server. This dedicated route enables the game data to bypass the clutter and all the traffic on a regular internet connection increasing the data transfer rate enhancing the ping rate and eliminating packet loss.

It is working fine on Dota 2 as I haven't played any other game on it. Might help you to solve your problem as well. It will also show you the spike before and after and all the complete stats of your network so you would actually see how much it improved your connection. No harm in trying.

Answer (score 0):

I was having some problems similar to this, and I saw some improvement by simply installing `wicd` and getting rid of `network-manager`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

After installation, simply open the wicd client with a `wicd-client` in the console, configure it, and reboot to make sure network-manager buggers off.

You may not get a wicd icon in the systray, as I didn't, but my WLAN appears much more stable now.

For reference, my wlan nic is an Intel AC 7625.