# Dota 2 lags on nVidia 650 ti

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, games, steam

I am a Windows user who is trying to switch to Linux completely. 
The only problem left for me is make Dota 2 run smoothly. 
At first Dota lagged a lot but then I installed drivers for my video card and it runs much better. It runs smoothly but every two minutes or when a big battle occurs, it starts lagging and almost stops. Then it is fine for a couple more minutes. I don't have these lags when I play from Windows. 
Is there anything I can try or is it as good as it gets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to tell you, but this is about as good as it gets:

> Well, that is the goal. Currently the DotA 2 client for Linux is not really performant resulting in low framerates (fps) and annoying lags. We hope this will be fixed some day.

- https://steamcommunity.com/groups/LinuxDotA

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 16.04, with lag spikes whenever there were many things happening on the screen.

Similar to the answer in [Dota 2 lag spikes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560857/dota-2-lag-spikes), switching to wicd instead of NetworkManager worked for me.

Basically, I followed these steps to get wicd installed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Then I ran `iwconfig` in a terminal to get the name of my wireless USB device and enter it into the Wcid Network Manager preferences (I had the same issue described in this post: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=982609).

Note that wicd doesn't have an icon on the system tray, so you'll have to run the Wicd Network Manager application to configure your settings.

Comment: While these articles may provide the answer for the OP, it is better to include the essential parts of the article with links for reference.